# E-Mail Site Admins in Django without using mail_admins()

Tags: python, django

I know this sounds kind of stupid, but as a beginner in Django (and even Python), I just want to know how I can access the email address from the ADMINS tuple, or maybe even access the admin name.

I read that tuples are semantic, kind of like lightweight structs. So if that's the case, I may be able to access those semantics and do something "dictionary-like", i.e. ADMINS['email']. Knowing this, how can I retrieve the admin email and name in the tuple?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ADMINS` is a setting.  You can access it as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.ADMINS
```

For example, to get all the email addresses as a list:

```
from django.conf import settings
admin_emails = [v for k,v in settings.ADMINS]
```

The settings docs:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/settings/

Comment: exactly what I needed. I came from PHP so the tuple concept came a bit weird, and I assumed that "for k, v" works like foreach($list as $k=$V) and thus only works with "associative array-like" structures which is in Python, dictionaries. Thanks :)